# Start custom SSH subsystem in Renci SSH.NET (an equivalent of ch.ethz ssh2.Session.StartSubSystem())

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ssh, ssh.net

I need to start a proprietary SSH subsystem on a mainframe.

I've migrate my project to dotnet core but it doesn't support ch.ethz.ssh2. I've change lib to Renci.SSHNET but there is no command to start a subsystem on a remote machine.

on ssh2

```
Session sess = conn.openSession();
int term_width = 0;
int term_height = 0;
sess.requestPTY("dumb", term_width, term_height, 0, 0, null);
sess.startSubSystem("xxx");
```

on renci.sshnet i've using SshClient

```
ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo(
    HostIp,
    Port,
    HostUser,
    new AuthenticationMethod[]{
        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(HostUser,HostPass.TrimEnd()),
    });
msshclient = new SshClient(connInfo);
msshclient.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be possible with the public API of SSH.NET.

But if you are willing to modify SSH.NET code, it should be trivial. Start in `Session.CreateChannelSession`.